# Core Data duplicate entries

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm importing data from an API that's giving me JSON data. Each object that gets added into core data has an attribute named "id". I want to be able to check if the id is already in core data after the initial import. I have written this code out for it so far:

```
    - (void)mergeData: (NSString *)entityDescription {
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", _bank.id]; // Bank is the entity
// id is the key from the raw JSON
            NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSError *error = nil;

            [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Banks" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
            [fetch setPredicate:pred];
            NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
            for (NSManagedObject *object in items) {
                // Loop over all the items and check to see if the ids match with any ids from the feed
                // if any of them don't match, add the new ids
                if (!match) {
    // add new object
    // I'm not sure how to implement this part            
            }

        }
```

But I know it's not complete and I'm not sure how to implement the rest of the code for this part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html), especially the section **Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently**, it's what you need.